# Change Display Mode on server with 3 GPUs

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-settings, gpgpu

First full disclosure I am new to the GPU world.

I have a server with a Quadro K620, and two Tesla V100-PCIE GPUs. None is used for graphical display.

Issuing the nvidia-smi -i X -q with X = 0, 1, 2 I can see that the display mode is on for the two Teslas and off for the Quadro.

I would like to change the display mode to off for both Teslas. How am I going to do this? I read the nvidia-smi documentation and there I can set the persistance-mode, virt-mode or accountig-mode. I could find nothing about the display mode. Trying the internet did not help me either. Does anybody have some suggestions?

I am using NVIDIA-SMI 418.40.04
CUDA Version: 10.1

Thank you very much in advance for any comment you might have,

Markus